# Correct way of Vector Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Can anyone please tell me whether its a vector implementation or not? If not, then **Question is** what's wrong with my code and how to implement vectors in correct way. Kindly guide.
P.S: I have added only partial code here. Does my PUSH function successfully implements VECTOR.

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    T *input;
    int top;
    int capacity;
public:
    Vector();
    ~Vector();
    void push(T x);
};
template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
    top = -1;
    capacity = 5;
    input = new T[capacity];
}
template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[]input;
}
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::push(T x)
{
    if (top + 1 == capacity)
    {
        T *vec = new T[capacity*2];
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        {
            vec[i] = input[i];
        }
        delete[]input; //Avoiding memory leak
        input = vec;
        capacity *= 2;
    }
        top++;
        input[top] = x;
}
```

I am adding complete runnable code. Its basically code of STACK that I wrote. But all I want to know is in this code whether I have successfully used VECTOR CONCEPT OR NOT. If not, What is the correct VECTOR Implementation.

```
#include"iostream"
template <class T>
class Mystack
{
private:
    T *input;
    int top;
    int capacity;
public:
    Mystack();
    ~Mystack();
    void push(T x);
    T pop();
    T topElement() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void print();
};
template <class T>
Mystack<T>::Mystack()
{
    top = -1;
    capacity = 5;
    input = new T[capacity];
}
template <class T>
Mystack<T>::~Mystack()
{
    delete[]input;
}
template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::push(T x)
{
    if (top + 1 == capacity)
    {
        T *vec = new T[capacity * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        {
            vec[i] = input[i];
        }
        delete[]input;
        input = vec;
        capacity *= capacity;
    }
    top++;
    input[top] = x;
}
template <class T>
T Mystack<T>::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Stack Underflow");
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The popped element is" << input[top];
        return input[top--];

    }
}
template <class T>
bool Mystack<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Is Empty" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not Empty" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
template <class T>
T Mystack<T>::topElement() const
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("No Element to Display");
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The top element is : " << input[top];
        return input[top];
    }
}
template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
    {
        std::cout << input[i] << " ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    Mystack<int> s1;
    Mystack<float> s2;
    Mystack<char> s3;
    int choice;
    int int_elem;
    float float_elem;
    char char_elem;
    std::cout << "Enter the type of stack" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. int" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. float" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. Char" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        int  ch = 1;
        while (ch > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n1. PUSH" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "2. TOP" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "3. IsEmpty" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "4. POP" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "5. EXIT" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "6. Print" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> ch;
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Enter the number to be pushed" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> int_elem;
                s1.push(int_elem);
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "Get the TOP Element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    s1.topElement();
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error:" << oor.what() << std::endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
                s1.isEmpty();
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    s1.pop();
                }
                catch (const std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                exit(0);
            case 6:
                s1.print();
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Enter a valid input";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        int  ch = 1;
        while (ch > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n1. PUSH" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "2. TOP" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "3. IsEmpty" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "4. POP" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "5. EXIT" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "6. Print" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> ch;
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Enter the number to be pushed" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> float_elem;
                s2.push(float_elem);
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "Get the TOP Element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    s2.topElement();
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error:" << oor.what() << std::endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
                s2.isEmpty();
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    s2.pop();
                }
                catch (const std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                exit(0);
            case 6:
                s2.print();
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Enter a valid input";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        int  ch = 1;
        while (ch > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n1. PUSH" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "2. TOP" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "3. IsEmpty" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "4. POP" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "5. EXIT" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "6. Print" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> ch;
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Enter the number to be pushed" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> char_elem;
                s3.push(char_elem);
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "Get the TOP Element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    s3.topElement();
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error:" << oor.what() << std::endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
                s3.isEmpty();
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    s3.pop();
                }
                catch (const std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                exit(0);
            case 6:
                s3.print();
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Enter a valid input";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Invalid Choice";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Why negative votes? I have added code snippet that I worked on. And have asked direct question also that "what's wrong in this implementation". Is SO only meant for experienced guys and not for students who are trying to learn something and need help!!

Comment: The question does not show any research effort, you do not appear to have used a debugger, you have also failed to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't respect rule of 3 (5). You require a `T` default constructible (you may avoid that with placement new).

Comment: I have used debugger and it worked. But I am not sure if I am really implementing vector. Because I don't wanna end up using some other concept thinking its a vector.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar : I have added the complete running code now.

Comment: @Jarod42 : I could not understand you point. Sorry. Can you please explain in layman terms. Thanks.

Comment: Rule of 3 means that if you have a destructor then you should also implement a copy constructor and a copy assignement constructor. I would suggest to take a look at the std::vector member functions http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/. This will give you further ideas. Adding begin() and end() for iterators is interesting for instance.

Comment: @tanz: see [Rule_of_three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) and [Placement_syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)

Comment: If there are no concrete problems with your code(that is, it works properly), it looks like this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the all the standard functions present in VECTOR STL. That should enhance your understanding of vectors. And the code in question is not proper implementation of VECTOR since there are many other functionality Vector STL provides.